# Shall we stop [naming] things?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [naming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) tag currently has 47 questions.  Should we eliminate it?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the [naming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) tag should be eliminated through burnination, since it adds no value.  Every piece of code (except simple [assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) and esoteric languages such as [brainfuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)) involves naming, and every answer is free to address any issue including naming.  Therefore, naming is an implied concern in every question, and the tag adds no value.

If a question is purely about naming with minimal code involved, it is likely off-topic for Code Review anyway.

Comment: Yeah. It can go, but we're talking about a manual clean up, right? It's only 47 questions. There may be other things to clean up.