# Let's add more [naming] to the blacklist

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

I happened to see that [naming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) was recreated and removed today.  In the past, there was also [high favorability](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/shall-we-stop-naming-things) towards burnination.  Many other bad meta tags have already been blacklisted, so should we finally add this one as well?

**Completion note:** [names](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) has also been blacklisted.

Comment: With what kind of summary/context were you thinking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes!

...except now I wonder why it wasn't blacklisted in the first place.

Anyway, [naming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) is absolutely a meta-tag that conveys concerns that should be expresed in plain English as part of the OP.

And we don't need that meta-tag.